# more efficent way of reading data from two table and writing them in a new one using batch

Tags: spring, algorithm, batch-file, db2

I'm trying to write a spring batch to move data from two tables to a single table. I'm having a problem now and I thought of many ways to solve this problem but I'm still wondering if there is a more efficent solution to my problem?
Basically the problem is, I have two tables lets call them `table A` and `table B` and their structure is as the following:

```
table A
column 1A   column 2A 
========   ========
bmw         123555
nissan      123456777
audi        12888
toyota      9800765
kia      85834945

table B
column 1B   column 2B
========   ========
12          caraudi
123456      carnissan
123         carbmw
0125        carvvv
88963       carbbn
```

what I'm trying to do is to create a table c from the batch's wrtier which holds all the data from `table B (column 1B and column 2B)`and `column 1A` only without losing any data from both tables and without writing duplicated data based on column 2A and column 1B. column A and column B have only one column in common `(coulmn 1B == column 2A)` but `column 2A` has a `3 digits suffix` added to each id so if we do a join and compare I have to use a `substr` method and it will be very slow coz I have huge tables. 
The other solution I thinked of is to have a reader for table A and write all results to tempA table without the suffix, then another reader that compare tables tempA and table B and write the data to table c as the following

```
table c
column 1A ( can be nullable because not all the records in column 2A exists in column 1B) 
column 1B
column 2B
```

so the table will look like this

```
table C
column 1c   column 2c   column 3c
=========   =========   =========
12          caraudi     audi
123456      carnissan   nissan
123         carbmw      bmw
0125        carvv       
88963       carbbn   
9800765                 toyota
85834945                kia
```

is this the bet way to solve the problem? or is there any other way that is more efficient?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version and platform of DB2 are you using? Some versions allow expression-based indexes that could reduce the likelihood of a scan.

Answer (score 0):

Before giving up on a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` from tableA to tableB (or a `FULL OUTER JOIN` if your query conditions require it) consider using `db2expln` or the Visual Explain utility in IBM Data Studio to determine the cost of some alternative ways to perform a "begins with" match on `VARCHAR` columns:

- `ON a.col2a LIKE b.col1b || '___'`
- `ON a.col2a >= b.col1b || '000' AND a.col2a <= b.col1b || '999'`

If 1b is a `CHAR` column, you might need to trim off its trailing spaces before concatenating additional characters to it: `RTRIM( b.col1b ) || '000'`

Assuming column 1b is indexed, one prefix-based matching predicate or another is bound to make a join between those two tables less expensive than creating, populating, and joining to your own temp table. If I'm wrong (or there are other complicating factors) and a temp table ends up being the best option, be sure to use a declared global temporary table (DGTT) so you can avoid the logging overhead of populating it.